# Autoload in subfolder

Tags: php

I have a folder structure like:

```
Root
+--Level1
|  +--index.php
|  |
|  \--Level2
|     +--myclass.php
```

index.php:

```
namespace Level1;

spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register();

Level2\myClass::myMethod();
```

class.php:

```
namespace Level1\Level2;
    class myClass{
    ...
    }
```

I want to use, in the index.php, the class inside myclass.php.

But when I call the class, I have this error:

**LogicException: Class Level1\Level2\myClass could not be loaded**

It seems it tries to load level1\level2\myclass.php, but I'm already at level1, so it should only load level2\myclass.php (otherwise the full path would be root\level1\level1\level2\myclass.php

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, to begin with, `class` is a reserved keyword. When you do `class Class` – php will hate you, `class Class(){}` also is not how you define classes in php, you don't need `()`. Begin with verifying the code in your example and updating the question with the valid one.

Comment: Yes sorry, it was only a placeholder name, I simplified the script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the 'auto loader' does not 'know' about your 'Root' directory.

The way that the 'default' **[spl_autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php)** works is to append the 'lowercase' namespace, as directores, that you specified and append them as directories to the directories in the **[include-path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)**.

Note: **it does NOT use 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'.**

To fix the issue that you are having then you have to include your 'Root' path in the **PHP 'include_path' .**

Here is some code that adds the 'Root' directory to the 'include_path'.

My 'Root' directory is **'testmysql'**.

The 'class' file in 'level1\level2' :

```
namespace Level1\Level2;

class myClass {

    public static function staticLocation()
    {
        echo '----------  ', '<br />';
        echo 'method    : ', __METHOD__, '<br />';
        echo 'class     : ', __CLASS__, '<br />';
        echo 'namespace : ', __NAMESPACE__, '<br />';
        echo 'directory : ', __DIR__, '<br />';
        echo 'filepath  : ', __FILE__, '<br />';
    }
}
```

The **index.php** that shows all the details:

```
namespace Level1;

spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register();

echo '<br />Document Root: ', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '<br />';

// Define the root path to my application top level directory (testmysql)
define('APP_ROOT',  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/testmysql');

echo '<br />', 'My Application Root directory: ', APP_ROOT, '<br />';

echo '<br />', 'This File: ', __FILE__, '<br />';
echo '<br />', 'Current Directory : ', __DIR__, '<br />';

echo '<br />', 'Include path (before): ', ini_get('include_path'), '<br />';
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') .';'. APP_ROOT .';');
echo '<br />', 'Include path (after): ', ini_get('include_path'), '<br />';

Level2\myClass::staticLocation();
```

Sample output on my system: PHP 5.3.18 on window xp.

```
P:/developer/xampp/htdocs

My Application Root directory: P:/developer/xampp/htdocs/testmysql

This File: P:\developer\xampp\htdocs\testmysql\level1\index.php

Current Directory : P:\developer\xampp\htdocs\testmysql\level1

Include path (before): .;P:\developer\xampp\php\PEAR

Include path (after): .;P:\developer\xampp\php\PEAR;P:/developer/xampp/htdocs/testmysql;
----------
method : Level1\Level2\myClass::staticLocation
class : Level1\Level2\myClass
namespace : Level1\Level2
directory : P:\developer\xampp\htdocs\testmysql\level1\level2
filepath : P:\developer\xampp\htdocs\testmysql\level1\level2\myClass.php
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer, I'll try

Comment: Perfect, so all I had to do was to add this line: `ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') .';'. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .';');`